# Image URL not accessible in an API Call

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to access an image URL in an API call in my react project but, the error message I'm getting is that the URL not defined as an error. Have tried to find the error but couldn't find it. Kindly assist in helping me to know what I'm doing wrong.

Below is my code. The place giving me a problem is commented out.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from "axios";
import { Card} from "react-bootstrap";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchCountryData();
  }
  fetchCountryData = async () => {
    const url = "https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds";
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      const data = await response.data;
      this.setState({
        data
      });
     
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <h1>React Component Life Cycle</h1>
      <h1>Calling API</h1>
      <div>
        {
          this.state.data.map((item, id) => (
          <div key={id}>
            {console.log(item)}



            <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
            {/* <Card.Img variant="top" src={item.image.url} /> This part is giving me the problem  */}
        <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title>{item.name}</Card.Title>
        <Card.Text>
        {item.origin}
      </Card.Text>
      <Card.Text>
      {item.temperament} 
      </Card.Text>
      <Card.Text>
      {item.weight.metric} 
      </Card.Text>
      <Card.Text>
      {item.description} 
      </Card.Text>
    {/* <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button> */}
    </Card.Body>
  </Card>









            {/* { <img src={item.image.url} alt=""/> }  Please why is this not working ? */}
            {/* {item.name} <br/>
            {item.origin} <br/>
            {item.temperament} <br/>
            {item.life_span} <br/>
            {item.weight.metric} <br/>
            {item.description} <br/> */}

          </div>
          ))
        }
        
      </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting. My first thought was that when the component renders, `item.image` object does not exist so that's why you cannot access a property in an undefined object. But then I realized it doesn't throw for `item.weight.metric`. I will be waiting to see what other people have to say about this.

However, the basic fix is you can simply use image link as `item.image && item.image.url` or shortly `item.image?.url` so it doesn't throw.